# Colored title of list of figure interfering with colored fancy header

Tags: table-of-contents, color, fancyhdr

I am writing a document where I want to have the title of List of Figures colored and the header as well (let's say in red). But it seems that the `\fancyhead[L]{\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{\leftmark}}` command is interfering with the coloring of the title `\renewcommand\listfigurename{\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{List of Figures}}`. The headers of the chapters are fine but not the one of List of Figures...

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{book} 


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\textcolor{red}{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}


\begin{document}

   
    
\renewcommand\listfigurename{\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{List of Figures}} 
\listoffigures


\chapter{X}

\def\z{
  \begin{figure}[htp]
  \caption{A}
  \end{figure}
}
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z \clearpage
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\clearpage
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\clearpage
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\clearpage
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to circumvent this issue and have both title and header of List of Figures colored? I tried `\markboth{ \textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{LIST OF FIGURES} }{\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{LIST OF FIGURES}}`. But it only gives a colored heading for the last page.

I would appreciate any help.

Fanny

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 0):

#### First Attempt

A brute attempt achieved by redefining `\listoffigures`. Note every time the `\listoffigures` is redefined either by different document class or by packages, you need to adjust the patching.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\color{red}\listfigurename}%
      \@mkboth{\color{red}\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\color{red}\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\chapter{X}

\def\z{
  \begin{figure}[htp]
  \caption{A}
  \end{figure}
}
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\clearpage
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\clearpage
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\clearpage
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\clearpage
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\clearpage

\end{document}
```

#### Second Attempt

Because of the use of `\MakeUppercase` in `\listoffigures`, every character in `\listfigurename` is first converted to uppercase. Hence `\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{...}` is converted to `\textcolor[RGB]{1,0,0}{...}`. Since `RGB` is a `[0, 255]^3` color space, `1, 0, 0` is so close to black (`0, 0, 0`) that it is indistinguishable with black.

Here is the trick:

```
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\textcolor[RGB]{255,0,0}{List of Figures}}
```

Note that normally name commands like `\listfigurename` should only contain plain characters without styling commands. Though I think it's ok to have some in your specific requirement.

#### Possible More Elegant Solution

Start a new page, change the style of `\chapter*` and page style, use `\listoffigures`, start another new page, and revert to normal style.